# How to limit certain MAC address or IP range using QoS - ZTE 931 VII

Tags: router, wireless-router, qos

I tried setting up some basic rules for my home router's QoS, but I haven't been successful so far.

What I want to do is to give certain MAC addresses a "privilege", and limit all the other computers in local network to 10 Mbps. So for example, if I'm streaming a HD movie or torrenting on a limited computer, I don't want it to affect the privileged computers (while gaming, for example).

In my current QoS setup, I'm creating a rule for MAC address of a certain computer and assigning it to Queue 1 (higher priority) and creating a rule for all other local IP addresses and assigning them to Queue 2 (lower priority) as well as limiting their bandwidth. However, this isn't working as it should.

Here are the screenshots of current QoS setup attempt:

[image]

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your privileged computer to a static IP outside of the DHCP Range.

set the privileged PC QOS rules with source and destination to the IP you statically set, and additionally set the mac of the adapter that's connecting to the network.

set the lower privileged PC source and destination to the DHCP pool of the network. (keep the privileged PC out of this range)

you should be setting a priority value for each queue.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiated_services

that should do it. you may have to reboot the router for the changes to take effect.

if your router is on 192.168.1.1 then do not have this in the second queue.
the valid range for a /24 network would be 2-254 (assuming your router is at 1)

i would recommend setting the DHCP pool to 192.168.1.11 - 192.168.1.254
and putting your privileged PC at lets say 192.168.1.5 that gives you eight other addresses you can set in the first priority queue.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. The router has 8 queues on default, 1-8, with 1 being the highest priority. Do I need to set a rule for the router (192.168.1.1) and if yes, does it need to be in higher priority queue than other rules (e.g. router in q1, privileged q2, limited q3)?

Comment: No, since your router is doing the actual queuing. It Is just prioritizing the traffic you designate, as it comes to the gateway (router). You are very welcome btw